# What is the best tool to track users on flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I have created a flutter app and I want to track my users path.
I want to track how many time they spend on each screen, how many time they played on my app etc.

Is it possible with firebase analytics ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools out there. I would suggest Matomo.
* OpenSource
* Easy to use
* Flutter Lib available

Tool:
https://github.com/matomo-org/
Flutter Lib:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_matomo

Comment: it's now outdated

Comment: The flutter_matomo package is indeed outdated. There are already two newer packages and I referenced them in a new answer that also answers the firebase question.

Answer (score 1):

With [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/screenviews) it seems to be available out of the box.
You can see a nice example here: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/firebase-analytics-2044e865efc4 .
You will see screen changes, session duration in form of length of event stream, and you can add your own events to that.

Three [Matomo integrations](https://pub.dev/packages?q=matomo) are available as commented in the other answer. [Matomo_forever](https://pub.dev/packages/matomo_forever) is self-described as being more portable (not restricted to mobile apps, also supporting browser-based flutter apps). [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) can be self-hosted and is also available as European-hosted Cloud service.

Comment: If your app is available in the EU this will require you to show a consent screen and get permission to send data to Google.

Comment: Hi @MartinBraun, can you clarify if your comment applies to Firebase only or also to for example self-hosted Matomo? The consent-screen topic is quite a different question than what was asked. See: https://matomo.org/cookie-consent-banners/

Comment: You can record any data of anybody without consent as long as you do not share it with a third party and as long as it won't allow you to identify the person outside of your application. Using Matomo while anonymizing your visitors IPs is already enough to avoid the need of an opt-in by the user, so I would always prefer Matomo. My comment was directed only towards the use of Firebase Analytics, I wasn't clear enough in my comment.